# How to make batch (concurrently) PUT calls using RestEasy?

Tags: rest, concurrency, resteasy, put

I am trying to make multiple **PUT requests** to a server and each of these are **independent**. Finally, all the response status codes are &&ed and function returns a boolean on success/failure. However, in this approach I have to wait for each response which increases the delay based on the number of put requests.

I was wondering if they can be made **concurrently thus getting a latency equal to the longest call** regardless of number of calls. (Assuming that the server can handle all of them at the same time).
Instead of writing a own wrapper wondering if **there is something RestEasy already provided.**

I am using RestEasy and currently this is how I am doing it:

```
public boolean makePuts(Entity[] entities) {
    boolean success = true;
    for (Entity entity : entities) {
        Response response = //Make put call using RestEasy.
        success = success && putContentAccepted(response);
    }
    return success;
}

private boolean putContentAccepted(final Response response) {
        return response != null &&
           ((response.getStatus() == Response.Status.NO_CONTENT.getStatusCode()) ||
           (response.getStatus() == Response.Status.CREATED.getStatusCode()) ||
           (response.getStatus() == Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode()));
    }
```

PS: I have typed the function and have not compiled it, please excuse me for any syntactical mistakes. The function sheds insight on what I am doing currently.

Thanks!

Harsha P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this using async and a CountDownLatch. Let me know if there is some better way.

```
final List<Future<Response>> futureList = new ArrayList<>();
final List<> responseList = new ArrayList<Response>();
final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(requestModels.size());
for (URI uri : uriList) {
    WebTarget target;
    //Use an input model object if there is need for entity, I am assuming just a list of URI. 
    //Rather take it as an object which has URI, Entity.
    futureList.add(target.request().async().put(null, new InvocationCallback<Response>() {
        @Override
        public void completed(Response response) {
            responseList.add(response);
        }

        @Override
        public void failed(Throwable throwable) {
            //handle error
        }
     }));
}
try {
    latch.await();
    return responseList;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        //handle it
    }
```